# How can I check the IVs of my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

[IVs](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values) are a very important thing in competitive Pokemon. Is there a way to check them easily?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, but it requires a few steps:

1. Complete the game
2. Go to the Battle Tower in Wyndom (top of the map)
3. Battle and defeat Leon (win 6 battles total)

This will give you access to the IV judge, which gives you information about the height of the IV per stat. To do this, press + in the Pokemon Box. Here's an overview of what the texts mean:

- No Good: 0
- Decent: 1- 10
- Pretty Good: 11 - 20
- Very Good: 21 - 29
- Fantastic: 30
- Best: 31

Here's an example of the IV judge:

[image: IV judge overview]

[Source](https://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-sword-shield/How_to_Unlock_the_IV_Checker_in_Pokemon_Sword_and_Shield_-_Individual_Values)