# What menu settings or features can be unlocked through non-story means?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

It seems the 'Rotom Phone' menu options get extended throughout the game with extra features. Sometimes these are awarded through just progressing the story (as is the case with Pokemon Camp and the Box system) but other features such as the [IV Judge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360362/28182), have a specific requirement to unlock that is easy to miss.

What 'hidden' options or features of the menu need to be found or earned through non-story means, and how does one unlock them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the [Hi-Tech Earbuds](https://www.serebii.net/pokearth/galar/motostoke.shtml#items) from an otherwise unremarkable NPC in Motostoke (outside the stadium). Obtaining these adds a few options to the Settings menu that let you change the volume of music and sound effects.